# Dependency Property Default Value

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I am new with WPF and dependency properties and my question might be totally newbie...

I have the following dependency property:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditableProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsEditable", typeof(bool), typeof(EditContactUserControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsEditablePropertyChanged));

    public bool IsEditable
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEditableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsEditableProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnIsEditablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditContactUserControl control = source as EditContactUserControl;

        bool isEditable = (bool)e.NewValue;

        if (isEditable)
            control.stackPanelButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            control.stackPanelButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

The problem is that I want to have the code in the `OnIsEditablePropertyChanged` to be executed also for the default value of my property, which doesn't happen.

What am I doing wrong, or how should I do this in your opiniion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are you setting the default value?

Comment: In the creation of the property: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false.. is this not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the visibility in code, you should **Bind** the Visibility property in XAML and use a boolean to Visibility Converter.

If you do this, it doesn't matter if the property is initialized or not.

Comment: Nice! This is what I am going to do. But still I find it inconvenient that a property's default value does not raise the PropertyChanged event. Anyhow... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The OnPropertyChanged callback won't be called on startup: The "default" value is in fact never really "set". Default: The value of the property when it isn't set.

If you want to execute some code at control startup, put it in the ApplyTemplate method override (in the case of a TemplatedControl) or at the end of your constructor (in the case of a UserControl)

Avoid duplicating this code in the constructor and in the property changed callback: Put it in a common method called by both ie:

```
void OnIsEditableChangedImpl(bool newValue)
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am currently doing, but I thought there might be a more sophisticated way to do this, that I probably miss...

Answer (score 0):

I think a much better approach would be to set up `stackPanelButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` in your XAML as default too, in which case you don't need to run all this code on startup!